# Displaying Post Title on Post Edit page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I'm trying to include the post title in a custom post type edit screen. For example if the post is called Biography, I want the edit page title to be 'Edit Biography'. I'm using the below code:

```
function my_post_register() {
 $mypagetitle = $post->post_title;
 $labels = array(
  'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$mypagetitle),
```

Why isn't this displaying the post title?

Comment: When are you calling this function? I can assume there is a timing issue here - shouldn't you already have registered your post type before you query for the post?

Comment: Yeah I'm calling this before registering the post type. So I guess I need a way of changing the labels after the post type has been created?

Comment: I would guess so. Look at the place in the PHP page that displays the title, and work backwards from there, to find the best place to edit the title and other labels, using a filter for example.

Comment: I've found out it's this bit of code in post.php: $title = $post_type_object->labels->edit_item; but I've got no idea how to filter it!

Comment: I don't remember exactly how it was at the time of asking, but this is definitely default behavior now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
function edit_screen_title() {
    global $post, $title, $action, $current_screen;

    if( isset( $current_screen->post_type ) && $current_screen->post_type == 'post' && $action == 'edit' )
        $title = 'Edit ' . $post->post_title;
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'edit_screen_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

two things I'd suggest. First try adding global $post as the first line in your function

```
global $post;
```

Also in places I've had trouble getting the post_title, then I found another function

```
$mypagetitle = single_post_title('', false);
```

You could try that - more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but I think it's more of a timing issue as Jan suggests above