# How do you change the title of the Edit Post page?

Tags: title

When editing a post if I look at the title of the tab, it says:

```
Edit Post < username -- WordPress
```

When you've got a lot of tabs open that's not very useful. More useful would be something like:

```
Edit Post - title of page
```

Please don't give a kneejerk `when you first create a post you don't know the title`. I'm talking about `Edit`ing an existing post.

I've seen this post which changes the title in the Edit screen (but not the HTML title): [Displaying Post Title on Post Edit page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/displaying-post-title-on-post-edit-page)

Comment: And what’s the point in showing in there value that you are editing? What, if you change the title?

Comment: Also keep in mind that posts can have the same title but differing slugs

Comment: You could enqueue your own custom JavaScript only on the admin edit post screen, and from there, have jQuery grab the Post Title. Add an if condition - if the Post Title is not empty, update the `<title>` tag to match.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22951/how-to-enqueue-scripts-on-custom-post-add-edit-pages for the enqueueing part; inspect elements for the jQuery part, and make sure to add jQuery as a dependency when you enqueue your custom script.